# Free, Limitless GeoJSON APIs for nation shapes?

Tags: geospatial, api, json, openstreetmap

I am looking for some API endpoints that return GeoJSON shapes for each nation. I am not interested in downloading shapefiles. I need some lightweight (not super accurate) nation shapes for every nation that I can call frequently to overlay on a map webapp.

Answer (score 1):

Although not an API, there are hosts of GeoJSON with quite a small size, for example, 251 KB: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json

raw data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json

---

If you need a web service, you can turn any (geo)Json into an API endpoint (either local or hosted). Here's one library doing that, although for sure there are many others: https://github.com/Noznoc/geojson-api

Comment: Another resource is the World Atlas (TopoJSON) https://github.com/topojson/world-atlas, particulary world.atlas.countries: https://github.com/topojson/world-atlas#world/110m.json_countries

Comment: And another one, based on OpenStreetMap: https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/